# How to invert columns for a large data set in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a large data set of approximately 900K rows (i.e. there are 182 countries with about 50-60 indicators per country across several years (1970-2014). I am trying to use Python to make "Indicator Codes" as the new column so it states all the relevant data by country by year for every relevant indicator. Keep in mind that all of the years (1970-2014) are not labelled under a single label (i.e. years)

Original Data Set

```
Country Indicator Code   2001 2001 2003 2004 

US      Enrollment Rate  99%  98%  97%  96% 

US      Literacy Rate    99%  93%  95%  98%
```

Goal for the output data set

```
Country  Year    Enrollment Rate Literacy Rate etc. 
US       2001     99%            99%
```

I've tried the following code

```
res2 = data.pivot_table(index=['Country_Code'], columns=['Indicator_Code'],
                 values=['2006','2007'], aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
```

This is close but the indicators are repeating for each year and the year appears to be 3D. I've tried moving all the years to the columns or index portions but that is just returning a Memory error.

```
 res = data.pivot_table(index=['Country_Code','1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980'], columns=['Indicator_Code'], aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
```

I've tried this but it's also not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

A nice problem; you need to change columns from wide-form to long-form ([melt, see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)) and then pivot the other columns

```
m = df.melt(id_vars=['Country', 'IndicatorCode'], var_name='Year')
m['value'] = pd.to_numeric(m['value'].str.strip(r'%'))
m = m.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'Year'], columns=['IndicatorCode'], 
                  values='value')
del m.columns.name
m.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(m)

  #Country  Year  EnrollmentRate  LiteracyRate
#0      US  2001              99            99
#1      US  2002              98            93
#2      US  2003              97            95
#3      US  2004              96            98
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the following code

    m = data.melt(id_vars=['Country_Code', 'Indicator_Code'], var_name='Year')
m['value'] = pd.to_numeric(m['value'].str.strip(r'%'))
m = m.pivot_table(index=['Country_Code', 'Year'], columns=['Indicator_Code'], 
                  values='value')
del m.columns.name
m.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(m) 

It's returning the following error: 
ValueError: Unable to parse string "Adjusted net enrolment rate, lower secondary, both sexes (%)"